# Looking for solution of a 9th grader's problem

Tags: lambert-w, elementary-functions

My 9th grade (USA) son was given the following problem as part of an exam (which flummoxed him and me):

Solve $3(x-2)^2+5 = 3^{x+2} +5$.

This can be reduced to something like 
$y^2 3^y = 3^3$, but any solution in elementary functions escapes me.

Is it straightforward to show that a solution using elementary functions does not exist?

**Clarification**:

The problem has a unique solution which can be found easily by numerical
techniques, but this is not something I would expect on a 9th grader's final exam.

**Clarification**:

I am trying to determine if a solution exists in terms of elementary functions. There is likely a typo. in the problem statement, but I am still interested in solubility.

Comment: Perhaps drawing a graph of both equations and showing they never intersect?

Comment: The problem has a unique solution, but I would not expect a 9th grader to use numerical solution techniques.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ydvoeoomfn ... Maybe there is a typo in the question ?

Comment: Make the kids do the plots http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B%28x-2%29%5E2%2C+3%5E%28x%2B1%29%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C0.31%7D

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: Perhaps, but in any event, I believe the problem as stated has no solutions in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @janmarqz: This is in the context of exact solutions. If an approximate answer was expected, then that should be stated as part of the problem.

Comment: Well, the plots show to anyone that the solution exists, but expect the kids are going to appreciate a proof that there is no exact technique to solve is beyond  their reach and however may this type of questions serve as an introduction, an invitations to learn other kind of techniques

Comment: Do you have a copy of the examination itself?

Comment: @WillJagy: I do not the teacher does not give the exams out. However, the problem has been separately confirmed by two other kids.

Comment: @janmarqz: My question is about the solubility in elementary functions.

Comment: Probably a mistake in the exam question. It happens.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say something like "Show that the equation $3(x-2)^2 + 5 = 3^{x+2} + 5$ has a solution."? $\qquad$

Comment: If the student is allowed to use a graphing calculator this isn't too big a problem, even for a 9th grader. I get .13481444 as the solution. However, learning how to solve this kind of problem in 9th grade isn't normal but one would expect some coverage beforehand in class with a graphing calculator otherwise this is bogus question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Yes, I am certain.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Do you know if there is there a theory that deals with the existence of solutions in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: I expect a typo of a sort I can't reverse engineer.  There's nothing nice about the numerical solution.

Comment: The two $5's$ suggest a typo.  I mean, they just cancel so why put them there?  I think one of them must be there in error.

Comment: @lulu: It is a problem for 9th graders. In any event, my question is about the solubility in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: The solution is a transcendental number (using Gelfond-Schneider).

Comment: @copper.hat  I get that, but there's an error somewhere. As stated it's a trivial exercise in the lambert function but not otherwise solvable.  Like i say, I'm "sure" one of the $5's$ is wrong.  They make no sense as they are.

Comment: @lulu: Using Lambert would be good, can you add a solution please?

Comment: @lulu No, I don't think Lambert W can do this one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  You are right.  My quick trick was just a blunder.

Comment: @copperhat.  My error, I got nothing besides the numerical value.  I've tried regrouping the parentheses...like maybe the left hand should be $3^{(x-2)^2+5}$ or something, but I can't produce a solvable form.

Comment: @lulu: Thanks anyway.

Comment: One slight aesthetic improvement: we'd like to solve $x^2e^{ax}=b$.

Comment: looking at the symmetry, maybe it is $3(x-2)^2+5 = 3^{x\color{red}{-}2} +5$

Comment: @farruhota: The three kids I asked all wrote $3^{x-2}$, but it does have a 'nice' solution at $x=3$.

Comment: that is what I mean, I tried to fix the equation so that 9th grader could easily handle. but yes, provided the equation has no typo, then it is a little too hard.

Comment: @farruhota: Sorry, I meant $3^{x+2}$. At least the other would have some justification.

Answer (score 2):

Don't over think it.   If you can't do it, do what *can* be done and give a *reasonable* explaination as to why more *cannot* be done.   If those reasons are correct, then you've correctly answered.

---

I would mostly expect a nineth grader to manage the following by hand:$$\begin{align}3(x-2)^2+5 &= 3^{x+2}+5\\ (x-2)^2&= 3^{x+1}\tag{$\star$}\\ 2\ln \lvert x-2\rvert &=(x+1)\ln 3\\ x&= 2\log_3\lvert x-2\rvert-1\end{align}$$
In an exam, the iterative expresson is as close to a solution as they might get, unless they are given access to a calulator to furnish an approximation.

Once they reach $\star$ they should recognise that no tidy solution will exist; $x$ just won't be expressable as elementary functions of integers since it occurs as both a base and an exponent.   They should mention that intuition.

**NB:** Depending on the course curriculum, the student *may* have encountered the *Lambert W* function.   If so, *that* deserves attention.   Check to see if examples of this have been covered in class, and revise.

For bonus points a student should sketch a graph to verify that a real solution does infact exist, and where it *approximately* may.   A sugestion of *about* $0.15$ from a *rough* graph would be rather nice ($0.1$ to $0.2$ is a good range).

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a solution in terms of elementary functions or a proof that one does not exist. I am aware of techniques for finding numerical solutions  graphing the system.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(x-2)^2=3^{x+1}$ and on can easily show that this has a unique real solution in the interval $(0,1).$

For a closed form solution, lets make a substitution $3^a=x-2$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then $3^{2a}=3^{x+1}$ and by the injectivity of exponentials $x=2a-1.$ Hence $3^a=2a-3$ and therefore [the solution](https://m.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.html#Examples_of_use) would be $$a=\dfrac{3-W(-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}2\ln 3)}{\ln 3}.$$

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately Lambert is not really elementary from a 9th grader's perspective.

Comment: @copper.hat: I do not think this has an elementary from solution (obviously I can't prove it :)). But I wanted show that it has a solution in terms of Lambert $W,$ because somebody in the comment section thought it cannot be done with $W.$

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent publication which expresses the generalized lambert function as a taylor series:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904

I do not know if that qualifies as an analytic solution, however I think even the Lambert function can't be considered as such.

It does apply to the equation $x^2e^{ax}=c$.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the generalized Lambert function, but would like to find a solution in terms of elementary functions or a proof that one does not exist.